# What is the use of -i with curl command

Tags: rest, curl

Used to check if the index (indices) exists or not. For example:

```
curl -XHEAD -i 'http://localhost:9200/twitter'
```

The HTTP status code indicates if the index exists or not. A 404 means it does not exist, and 200 means it does.

What is the use of `-i` option in above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to cURL, I suppose. So it means it should be written in [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html):

> Different protocols provide different ways of getting detailed
>   information   about specific files/documents. To get curl to show
>   detailed information   about a single file, you should use -I/--head
>   option. It displays all available info on a single file for HTTP and
>   FTP. The HTTP information is a lot more extensive.

Or alternatively in [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> **-i, --include**
>
> (HTTP) Include the HTTP-header in the output. The HTTP-header includes
>   things like server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and
>   more...

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: @PradeepMalviya If this is what you were looking for and is correct, perhaps mark it as correct answer, so other people could find this information easier?